# How can I copy/paste files in the terminal window (SSH)?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I am new to ubuntu and my friend told me to SSH into my IPod so i can put/remove songs on it.
I've been succesfully ssh'ing into it but i do not know how to copy and paste my songs from my Home Directory into my iPod. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I do know basic commands like `ls, cd, pwd,` etc. I do know the `cp` command but cannot utilize it.

Comment: The question should be closed as its to broad (answers are good but the question maybe wont be visible to users searching for the problem, if rephrased it might be duplicate. The user also didnt pick an answer inviting score hunters (see last posts)

Answer (score 9):

Time to learn a new command!  :)

To learn more about it:

```
man scp
```

Secure Copy allows you to copy the contents of your friends directories to your local system.

So you mention you are comfortable with using SSH. Let say that your friends IP address is `192.168.1.100`. and your username is `joe`.  The files on your friends computer are located in `/share/music/`.

> Open a terminal window using "Ctrl-Alt-T" or use the Dash Search Bar

Now to copy individual files issue the following:

```
scp joe@192.168.1.100:/share/music/filename1.mp3 .
```

What this says is, ssh into your friend's computer at 192.168.1.100 with the username `joe` and copy the mp3 file `/share/music/filename1.mp3`  to your local present working directory (note the period)

You can actually specify a location to save the mp3 other than your present working directory

```
scp joe@192.168.1.100:/share/music/filename1.mp3 /var/tmp
```

So in the example above, I'm saving the mp3 to `/var/tmp`

Just make sure that you have proper permissions to the directory your saving too.

Now, to save whole directories, you need to use the recursive flag `-r`

```
scp -r joe@192.168.1.100:/share/music/album1 /var/tmp/
```

So now all the mp3's in `/share/music/album1` will save to `/var/tmp/`

Comment: Why do you prefix all your command lines with a # symbol?

Comment: “Time to learn a new command!” And, apparently, the location of the Shift and Apostrophe keys. :-)

Comment: sorry for my uber n00b-ness, but i understood completely everything you said and for my case my line was "scp Khalistan@192.168.10.103:/home/singh/Pictures/pics /var/mobile/Media/Photos" whereas Khalistan is my iPod and the /home...pics is the file i want to move at the moment. please tell me if you see any problems with this. also, i got a error, "ssh: connect to host 192.168.10.103 port 22: No route to host" any help would be apperciated and i thank you so much for writing such a complete and helpful response.

Comment: @GurjitSingh  I don't see any problems with what you asked. If your getting an error "No Route to host" it's most likely a problem with the networking configuration. Are you sure you know both IP Addresses of your systems? What happens when you run '#ifconfig -a  'on each system?

Comment: its to a ipod so i cannot do a ipconfig but im sure the ip is 192.168.10.103

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh My thoughts exactly. I suggested an edit that fixes this among minor other issues.

Comment: @GurjitSingh have you jailbroken your iPod? Non-jailbroken iPods do not allow incoming SSH connections.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `scp` command in terminal if you want to, but you don't *have* to do it in terminal.

Just open a new Nautilus window and select Go - Location... from the menu. This will open an input box where you need to put the connection string, something like

```
sftp://user@ip.add.re.ss/path/to/directory
```

Hit Enter, it'll ask you for password, and that's it:

[image: SFTP with Nautilus]

Then you can just drag and drop the files from another Nautilus window

Comment: @ sergey thanks but i just wanted to do this from the terminal, its an ego thing lol

Answer (score 0):

you can send a file with SCP too:

```
scp filename username@hostname:/path/to/send/to
```

You can also use an IP instead of host name:

```
scp filename username@10.0.0.1:/path/to/send/to
```

Answer (score -1):

Its easy. Suppose You need to move a file to secure directory. Use the following command after opening terminal (from the directory in which the file to moved is situated)--

my whole path was ziad@Cornelious:~/Work$ sudo mv master /var/www/html

In this case "master" folder was in "Work" directory/folder.
Use the following command--

sudo mv master /var/www/html

here i moved master folder to html folder which is a secure folder.

Comment: It's not too clear what you're saying... Would you please clarify a bit?

Comment: open terminal in the directory in which the file/folder you want to copy is situated. just use sudo mv "name of the directory" "location of your target folder" and it will work.